# Prevent pyttsx3 from freezing the GUI

Tags: python, multithreading, kivy

I have built my Kivy GUI which works with pyttsx3 for speech output, but when I run the pyttsx3 it blocks the main thread thus causing the GUI to freeze.

How do I run pyttsx3 on another thread and the output be heard from the main thread or is there a way to run pyttsx3 without blocking the main thread and prevent it from freezing my Kivy GUI?

This is a sample code I have created, when you click the button it should print the text from the textbox, but it causes the GUI to freeze when the pyttsx3 runs:

```
import pyttsx3
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import App



engine = pyttsx3.init()

engine.setProperty('rate', 150)
engine.setProperty('volume', 1)

class example(App):

    def build(self):

        layout = FloatLayout()

        self.textbox = TextInput(text="", multiline=False, font_size=12, size_hint_y=None, size_hint_x=None, width = 150, height = 30, pos_hint= {"x":0.4, "y":0.8})



        self.btnText = Button(text="Print text", font_size=12, size_hint_y=None, size_hint_x=None, width = 150, height = 30, pos_hint= {"x":0.4, "y":0.6})
        self.btnText.bind(on_press=self.print)


        layout.add_widget(self.textbox)
        layout.add_widget(self.btnText)

        return layout

    def print(self, instance):
        engine.say("this is an example of kivy being blocked my pyttsx3")
        engine.runAndWait()
        print(self.textbox.text)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    example().run()
```

I tried doing this below:

```
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=engine.say, args = ("some text here",))
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=engine.runAndWait(),)
thread2.start()
thread2.join()
```

but the above code still blocks the thread and causes the Kivy GUI to freeze.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As he points out you have to run it in a thread:

```py
import threading

# ...

class example(App):
    # ...

    def print(self, instance):
        threading.Thread(
            target=self.run_pyttsx3, args=(self.textbox.text,), daemon=True
        ).start()

    def run_pyttsx3(self, text):
        engine.say(text)
        engine.runAndWait()

# ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much @eyllanesc i have a similar problem with loading images to kivy.Image() when i run on another thread the data doesn't show on the app

Comment: Yes i saw his post i tried implementing and failed @eyllanesc,